# How to get a reference to a Google map marker in order to showWindow?

Tags: android, google-maps, google-maps-markers

I have a Google map with markers on it. On creation, the ID of the marker gets put into a hash map. I want the map to open up and automatically show the window, but how do I get a reference to the marker using the hash map?

```
Iterator it = markerMap.entrySet().iterator();
while (it.hasNext()) {
Map.Entry pairs = (Map.Entry)it.next();
if (String.valueOf(pairs.getValue()).equals(strID))  {   //when these match

    //need to showInfowindow here??? But how?                

    break;  //exit as match found
    }
 }
```

Edit: pairs.getValue is a marker, strID is the _id from the underlying SQLite database. When I try to get a reference to the marker in the Hashmap, I get a 'required: Marker   found: Object' incompatibility error. The code to set up the Hashmap is:

```
private HashMap<Marker, Integer> markerMap = new HashMap<Marker, Integer>();
```

The code to set the marker and put it in the Hashmap is:

```
m = mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
    .position(new LatLng(lat, lon))
    .title(c.getString(3))
    .snippet(strIcon.toUpperCase())
    .icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromAsset(strIcon + ".png")));
markerMap.put(m, Integer.parseInt(c.getString(0)));
```

I know the code is a bit clunky and needs tidying up - but once pairs.getValue() and strID match, then the right marker has been identified, but how do I then get a reference to the marker to call showInfowindow?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Why you don't want to put marker into HashMap/ArrayList instead of id?

Comment: Yup, like Fox in socks said, you have to put the actual markers into a Map, not only the id. The GoogleMap does not have a method to give you the Markers it displays.

Comment: Thanks both. I've updated the question to make it clearer.